# logistic regression derivative

Tags: regression, logistic

Our equation for negative log likelihood loss function for logistic regression with regularized maximum likelihood is:

$L(\beta) = -\sum^{n}_{i=1} log P(y_i|x_i) + \lambda \vert \vert \beta \vert \vert^2$

And it's derivative is:

$\Delta L(\beta) = \frac{\partial L(\beta)^T}{\partial \beta} = \sum^{n}_{i=1}(p_i - y_i)\phi(x_i)+2\lambda\textbf{I}\beta = X^T(p-y)+2\lambda\textbf{I}\beta$

I am trying to understand what does the identity matrix do there. So far I thought, if you multiply the identity matrix with a scalar that would give you the scalar "embedded" diagonally in the matrix. But isn't elementwise multiplication with a scalar doing the same thing as multiplication with such a matrix? What is the reason for including it in this equation then?

Comment: That does not look like maximum likelihood since it contains a regularization term!

Comment: I was under the impression that minimizing the negative log likelihood is equivalent to the maximum likelihood estimation. I would not be surprised if I turned out to be wrong.

Comment: Well, that is correct. But you have a term $+\lambda \Vert \beta \Vert^2$ which is not part of the likelihood, that looks like a regularization term (in fact, ridge). So this would be *regularized* maximum likelihood.

Comment: Well, since (as you say) $\boldsymbol{I} \beta = \beta$ you can just drop the identity matrix!